# KERAS MNIST：AttributeError: type object 'h5py.h5.H5PYConfig' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, anaconda

I’m learning how to write a CNN program recently. At the very beginning I wrote a handwriting-based program that reads MNIST and executed it successfully. However, because the learning speed of tensorflow is too slow, I installed and established a tensorflow-gpu operating environment. But after I created the environment and successfully executed it, I got an error when reviewing the program the next day. And even the environment created by Anaconda itself had the same error.

When executing `from keras.datasets import mnist`
Error problems are as follows

```
<ipython-input-3-ab413e7a8b2b> in <module>
----> 1 from keras.datasets import mnist

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\keras\__init__.py in <module>
     19 """
     20 # pylint: disable=unused-import
---> 21 from tensorflow.python import tf2
     22 from keras import distribute
     twenty three 

D:\Study\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>
     39 import sys as _sys
     40
---> 41 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     42 from tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader import LazyLoader as _LazyLoader
     43

D:\Study\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>
     46 from tensorflow.python import data
     47 from tensorflow.python import distribute
---> 48 from tensorflow.python import keras
     49 from tensorflow.python.feature_column import feature_column_lib as feature_column
     50 from tensorflow.python.layers import layers

D:\Study\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\__init__.py in <module>
     twenty three 
     24 # See b/110718070#comment18 for more details about this import.
---> 25 from tensorflow.python.keras import models
     26
     27 from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.input_layer import Input

D:\Study\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\models.py in <module>
     20 from tensorflow.python.keras import metrics as metrics_module
     21 from tensorflow.python.keras import optimizer_v1
---> 22 from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import functional
     23 from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import sequential
     24 from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import training

D:\Study\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\functional.py in <module>
     30 from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import input_spec
     31 from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import node as node_module
---> 32 from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import training as training_lib
     33 from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import training_utils
     34 from tensorflow.python.keras.saving.saved_model import network_serialization

D:\Study\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in <module>
     49 from tensorflow.python.keras.mixed_precision import policy
     50 from tensorflow.python.keras.saving import hdf5_format
---> 51 from tensorflow.python.keras.saving import save
     52 from tensorflow.python.keras.saving import saving_utils
     53 from tensorflow.python.keras.saving.saved_model import json_utils

D:\Study\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\save.py in <module>
     28 # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
     29 try:
---> 30 import h5py
     31 except ImportError:
     32 h5py = None

D:\Study\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\h5py\__init__.py in <module>
     32 raise
     33
---> 34 from. Import version
     35
     36 if version.hdf5_version_tuple != version.hdf5_built_version_tuple:

D:\Study\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\h5py\version.py in <module>
     15
     16 from collections import namedtuple
---> 17 from. Import h5 as _h5
     18 import sys
     19 import numpy

h5py\h5.pyx in init h5py.h5()

AttributeError: type object'h5py.h5.H5PYConfig' has no attribute'__reduce_cython__'
```

I have searched many articles before, including related answers on this website, but it doesn’t work whether it’s reinstalling h5py or downgrading tensorflow and h5py. Does anyone have a better answer?

PS.Because I’m not sure if the environment was set up wrong, I also posted the conda list,

```
# packages in environment at D:\Study\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_anaconda_depends         2020.07                  py38_0
_tflow_select             2.3.0                     eigen
absl-py                   0.13.0           py38haa95532_0
aiohttp                   3.7.4            py38h2bbff1b_1
alabaster                 0.7.12             pyhd3eb1b0_0
anaconda                  0.0.1.1                  pypi_0    pypi
anaconda-client           1.8.0            py38haa95532_0
anaconda-project          0.10.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0
anyio                     2.2.0            py38haa95532_2
appdirs                   1.4.4                      py_0
argh                      0.26.2                   py38_0
argon2-cffi               20.1.0           py38h2bbff1b_1
arrow                     0.13.1                   py38_0
asn1crypto                1.4.0                      py_0
astor                     0.8.1            py38haa95532_0
astroid                   2.6.5            py38haa95532_0
astropy                   4.2.1            py38h2bbff1b_1
astunparse                1.6.3                      py_0
async-timeout             3.0.1            py38haa95532_0
async_generator           1.10               pyhd3eb1b0_0
atomicwrites              1.4.0                      py_0
attrs                     21.2.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
autopep8                  1.5.6              pyhd3eb1b0_0
babel                     2.9.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
backcall                  0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
backports                 1.0                pyhd3eb1b0_2
backports.shutil_get_terminal_size 1.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_3
bcrypt                    3.2.0            py38he774522_0
beautifulsoup4            4.9.3              pyha847dfd_0
binaryornot               0.4.4              pyhd3eb1b0_1
bitarray                  2.1.0            py38h2bbff1b_1
bkcharts                  0.2                      py38_0
black                     19.10b0                    py_0
blas                      1.0                         mkl
bleach                    3.3.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
blinker                   1.4              py38haa95532_0
blosc                     1.21.0               h19a0ad4_0
bokeh                     2.3.3            py38haa95532_0
boto                      2.49.0                   py38_0
bottleneck                1.3.2            py38h2a96729_1
brotli                    1.0.9                ha925a31_2
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py38h2bbff1b_1003
bzip2                     1.0.8                he774522_0
ca-certificates           2021.7.5             haa95532_1
cachetools                4.2.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
certifi                   2021.5.30                pypi_0    pypi
cffi                      1.14.6           py38h2bbff1b_0
cfitsio                   3.470                he774522_6
chardet                   3.0.4           py38haa95532_1003
charls                    2.2.0                h6c2663c_0
charset-normalizer        2.0.3                    pypi_0    pypi
click                     8.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
cloudpickle               1.6.0                      py_0
clyent                    1.2.2                    py38_1
colorama                  0.4.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
comtypes                  1.1.10          py38haa95532_1002
conda                     4.10.3           py38haa95532_0
conda-env                 2.6.0                         1
conda-pack                0.6.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
conda-package-handling    1.7.3            py38h8cc25b3_1
console_shortcut          0.1.1                         4
contextlib2               0.6.0.post1                py_0
cookiecutter              1.7.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
coverage                  5.5              py38h2bbff1b_2
cryptography              3.4.7            py38h71e12ea_0
curl                      7.71.1               h2a8f88b_1
cycler                    0.10.0                   py38_0
cython                    0.29.24          py38hd77b12b_0
cytoolz                   0.11.0           py38he774522_0
dask                      2021.7.0           pyhd3eb1b0_0
dask-core                 2021.7.0           pyhd3eb1b0_0
decorator                 5.0.9              pyhd3eb1b0_0
defusedxml                0.7.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
diff-match-patch          20200713                   py_0
distributed               2021.7.0         py38haa95532_0
docutils                  0.17.1           py38haa95532_1
entrypoints               0.3                      py38_0
et_xmlfile                1.1.0            py38haa95532_0
fastcache                 1.1.0            py38he774522_0
filelock                  3.0.12             pyhd3eb1b0_1
flake8                    3.9.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
flask                     1.1.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
flatbuffers               1.12                     pypi_0    pypi
freetype                  2.10.4               hd328e21_0
fsspec                    2021.7.0           pyhd3eb1b0_0
future                    0.18.2                   py38_1
gast                      0.4.0                      py_0
get_terminal_size         1.0.0                h38e98db_0
gevent                    21.1.2           py38h2bbff1b_1
giflib                    5.2.1                h62dcd97_0
glob2                     0.7                pyhd3eb1b0_0
gmpy2                     2.0.8            py38h7edee0f_3
google-auth               1.33.1                   pypi_0    pypi
google-auth-oauthlib      0.4.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
google-pasta              0.2.0                      py_0
greenlet                  1.1.0            py38hd77b12b_0
grpcio                    1.34.1                   pypi_0    pypi
h5py                      3.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
hdf5                      1.10.4               h7ebc959_0
heapdict                  1.0.1                      py_0
html5lib                  1.1                        py_0
icc_rt                    2019.0.0             h0cc432a_1
icu                       58.2                 ha925a31_3
idna                      3.2                      pypi_0    pypi
imagecodecs               2021.6.8         py38h5da4933_0
imageio                   2.9.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
imagesize                 1.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
importlib-metadata        3.10.0           py38haa95532_0
importlib_metadata        3.10.0               hd3eb1b0_0
inflection                0.5.1            py38haa95532_0
iniconfig                 1.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
intel-openmp              2021.3.0          haa95532_3372
intervaltree              3.1.0                      py_0
ipykernel                 5.3.4            py38h5ca1d4c_0
ipython                   7.22.0           py38hd4e2768_0
ipython_genutils          0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
ipywidgets                7.6.3              pyhd3eb1b0_1
isort                     5.9.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
itsdangerous              2.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jdcal                     1.4.1                      py_0
jedi                      0.17.2           py38haa95532_1
jinja2                    2.11.3             pyhd3eb1b0_0
jinja2-time               0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_2
joblib                    1.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jpeg                      9b                   hb83a4c4_2
json5                     0.9.6              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jsonschema                3.2.0                      py_2
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py38_7
jupyter-packaging         0.7.12             pyhd3eb1b0_0
jupyter_client            6.1.12             pyhd3eb1b0_0
jupyter_console           6.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jupyter_core              4.7.1            py38haa95532_0
jupyter_server            1.4.1            py38haa95532_0
jupyterlab                3.0.14             pyhd3eb1b0_1
jupyterlab_pygments       0.1.2                      py_0
jupyterlab_server         2.6.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jupyterlab_widgets        1.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
keras                     2.4.3                         0
keras-applications        1.0.8                      py_1
keras-base                2.4.3                      py_0
keras-datasets            0.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
keras-nightly             2.5.0.dev2021032900          pypi_0    pypi
keras-preprocessing       1.1.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
keyring                   23.0.1           py38haa95532_0
kiwisolver                1.3.1            py38hd77b12b_0
krb5                      1.18.2               hc04afaa_0
lazy-object-proxy         1.6.0            py38h2bbff1b_0
lcms2                     2.12                 h83e58a3_0
lerc                      2.2.1                hd77b12b_0
libaec                    1.0.4                h33f27b4_1
libarchive                3.4.2                h5e25573_0
libcurl                   7.71.1               h2a8f88b_1
libdeflate                1.7                  h2bbff1b_5
libiconv                  1.15                 h1df5818_7
liblief                   0.10.1               ha925a31_0
libllvm9                  9.0.1                h21ff451_0
libpng                    1.6.37               h2a8f88b_0
libprotobuf               3.14.0               h23ce68f_0
libsodium                 1.0.18               h62dcd97_0
libspatialindex           1.9.3                h6c2663c_0
libssh2                   1.9.0                h7a1dbc1_1
libtiff                   4.2.0                hd0e1b90_0
libxml2                   2.9.12               h0ad7f3c_0
libxslt                   1.1.34               he774522_0
libzopfli                 1.0.3                ha925a31_0
llvmlite                  0.36.0           py38h34b8924_4
locket                    0.2.1            py38haa95532_1
lxml                      4.6.3            py38h9b66d53_0
lz4-c                     1.9.3                h2bbff1b_0
lzo                       2.10                 he774522_2
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6
m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2
markdown                  3.3.4            py38haa95532_0
markupsafe                1.1.1            py38he774522_0
matplotlib                3.3.4            py38haa95532_0
matplotlib-base           3.3.4            py38h49ac443_0
mccabe                    0.6.1                    py38_1
menuinst                  1.4.16           py38he774522_1
mistune                   0.8.4           py38he774522_1000
mkl                       2021.3.0           haa95532_524
mkl-service               2.4.0            py38h2bbff1b_0
mkl_fft                   1.3.0            py38h277e83a_2
mkl_random                1.2.2            py38hf11a4ad_0
mock                      4.0.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
more-itertools            8.8.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
mpc                       1.1.0                h7edee0f_1
mpfr                      4.0.2                h62dcd97_1
mpir                      3.0.0                hec2e145_1
mpmath                    1.2.1                    pypi_0    pypi
msgpack-python            1.0.2            py38h59b6b97_1
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1
multidict                 5.1.0            py38h2bbff1b_2
multipledispatch          0.6.0                    py38_0
mypy_extensions           0.4.3                    py38_0
nbclassic                 0.2.6              pyhd3eb1b0_0
nbclient                  0.5.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
nbconvert                 6.1.0            py38haa95532_0
nbformat                  5.1.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
ndindex                   1.5.2                    pypi_0    pypi
nest-asyncio              1.5.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
networkx                  2.6.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
nltk                      3.6.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
nose                      1.3.7           pyhd3eb1b0_1006
notebook                  6.4.0            py38haa95532_0
numba                     0.53.1           py38hf11a4ad_0
numexpr                   2.7.3            py38hb80d3ca_1
numpy                     1.19.5                   pypi_0    pypi
numpy-base                1.20.3           py38hc2deb75_0
numpydoc                  1.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
oauthlib                  3.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
olefile                   0.46                       py_0
openjpeg                  2.3.0                h5ec785f_1
openpyxl                  3.0.7              pyhd3eb1b0_0
openssl                   1.1.1k               h2bbff1b_0
opt_einsum                3.3.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
packaging                 21.0               pyhd3eb1b0_0
pandas                    1.3.0            py38hd77b12b_0
pandoc                    2.12                 haa95532_0
pandocfilters             1.4.3            py38haa95532_1
paramiko                  2.7.2                      py_0
parso                     0.7.0                      py_0
partd                     1.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
path                      16.0.0           py38haa95532_0
path.py                   12.5.0                        0
pathlib2                  2.3.6            py38haa95532_2
pathspec                  0.7.0                      py_0
pathtools                 0.1.2                      py_1
patsy                     0.5.1                    py38_0
pep8                      1.7.1                    py38_0
pexpect                   4.8.0              pyhd3eb1b0_3
pickleshare               0.7.5           pyhd3eb1b0_1003
pillow                    8.3.1            py38h4fa10fc_0
pip                       21.1.3           py38haa95532_0
pkginfo                   1.7.1            py38haa95532_0
pluggy                    0.13.1           py38haa95532_0
ply                       3.11                     py38_0
powershell_shortcut       0.0.1                         3
poyo                      0.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
prometheus_client         0.11.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
prompt-toolkit            3.0.17             pyh06a4308_0
prompt_toolkit            3.0.17               hd3eb1b0_0
protobuf                  3.17.3                   pypi_0    pypi
psutil                    5.8.0            py38h2bbff1b_1
ptyprocess                0.7.0              pyhd3eb1b0_2
py                        1.10.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
py-lief                   0.10.1           py38ha925a31_0
pyasn1                    0.4.8                      py_0
pyasn1-modules            0.2.8                    pypi_0    pypi
pycodestyle               2.6.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pycosat                   0.6.3            py38h2bbff1b_0
pycparser                 2.20                       py_2
pycurl                    7.43.0.6         py38h7a1dbc1_0
pydocstyle                6.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyerfa                    2.0.0            py38h2bbff1b_0
pyflakes                  2.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pygments                  2.9.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyjwt                     2.1.0            py38haa95532_0
pylint                    2.9.3            py38haa95532_1
pyls-black                0.4.6                hd3eb1b0_0
pyls-spyder               0.3.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pynacl                    1.4.0            py38h62dcd97_1
pyodbc                    4.0.31           py38hd77b12b_0
pyopenssl                 20.0.1             pyhd3eb1b0_1
pyparsing                 2.4.7              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyqt                      5.9.2            py38ha925a31_4
pyreadline                2.1                      py38_1
pyrsistent                0.17.3           py38he774522_0
pysocks                   1.7.1            py38haa95532_0
pytables                  3.6.1            py38ha5be198_0
pytest                    6.2.4            py38haa95532_2
python                    3.8.10               hdbf39b2_7
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
python-jsonrpc-server     0.4.0                      py_0
python-language-server    0.36.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0
python-libarchive-c       2.9                pyhd3eb1b0_1
python-slugify            5.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pytz                      2021.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0
pywavelets                1.1.1            py38he774522_2
pywin32                   227              py38he774522_1
pywin32-ctypes            0.2.0                 py38_1000
pywinpty                  0.5.7                    py38_0
pyyaml                    5.4.1            py38h2bbff1b_1
pyzmq                     20.0.0           py38hd77b12b_1
qdarkstyle                3.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
qstylizer                 0.1.10             pyhd3eb1b0_0
qt                        5.9.7            vc14h73c81de_0
qtawesome                 1.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
qtconsole                 5.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
qtpy                      1.9.0                      py_0
regex                     2021.7.6         py38h2bbff1b_0
requests                  2.26.0                   pypi_0    pypi
requests-oauthlib         1.3.0                      py_0
rope                      0.19.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
rsa                       4.7.2              pyhd3eb1b0_1
rtree                     0.9.7            py38h2eaa2aa_1
ruamel_yaml               0.15.100         py38h2bbff1b_0
scikit-image              0.18.1           py38hf11a4ad_0
scikit-learn              0.24.2           py38hf11a4ad_1
scipy                     1.6.2            py38h66253e8_1
seaborn                   0.11.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0
send2trash                1.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
setuptools                57.4.0                   pypi_0    pypi
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py38_2
singledispatch            3.6.2           pyhd3eb1b0_1001
sip                       4.19.13          py38ha925a31_0
six                       1.16.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
snappy                    1.1.8                h33f27b4_0
sniffio                   1.2.0            py38haa95532_1
snowballstemmer           2.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sortedcollections         2.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sortedcontainers          2.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
soupsieve                 2.2.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinx                    4.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib             1.0                      py38_1
sphinxcontrib-applehelp   1.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-devhelp     1.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp    2.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-jsmath      1.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-qthelp      1.0.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-websupport  1.2.4                      py_0
spyder                    5.0.5            py38haa95532_2
spyder-kernels            2.0.5            py38haa95532_0
sqlalchemy                1.4.22           py38h2bbff1b_0
sqlite                    3.36.0               h2bbff1b_0
statsmodels               0.12.2           py38h2bbff1b_0
sympy                     1.8              py38haa95532_0
tbb                       2020.3               h74a9793_0
tblib                     1.7.0                      py_0
tensorboard               2.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard-data-server   0.6.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow                2.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-base           2.3.0           eigen_py38h75a453f_0
tensorflow-estimator      2.5.0              pyh7b7c402_0
tensorflow-gpu            2.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
termcolor                 1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
terminado                 0.9.4            py38haa95532_0
testpath                  0.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
text-unidecode            1.3                        py_0
textdistance              4.2.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
threadpoolctl             2.2.0              pyhb85f177_0
three-merge               0.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
tifffile                  2021.4.8           pyhd3eb1b0_2
tinycss                   0.4             pyhd3eb1b0_1002
tk                        8.6.10               he774522_0
toml                      0.10.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0
toolz                     0.11.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0
tornado                   6.1              py38h2bbff1b_0
tqdm                      4.61.2             pyhd3eb1b0_1
traitlets                 5.0.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0
typed-ast                 1.4.3            py38h2bbff1b_1
typing-extensions         3.7.4.3                  pypi_0    pypi
typing_extensions         3.10.0.0           pyh06a4308_0
ujson                     4.0.2            py38hd77b12b_0
unicodecsv                0.14.1                   py38_0
unidecode                 1.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
urllib3                   1.26.6             pyhd3eb1b0_1
vc                        14.2                 h21ff451_1
versioned-hdf5            1.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
vs2015_runtime            14.27.29016          h5e58377_2
watchdog                  2.1.3            py38haa95532_0
wcwidth                   0.2.5                      py_0
webencodings              0.5.1                    py38_1
werkzeug                  2.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
wheel                     0.36.2                   pypi_0    pypi
whichcraft                0.6.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
widgetsnbextension        3.5.1                    py38_0
win_inet_pton             1.1.0            py38haa95532_0
win_unicode_console       0.5                      py38_0
wincertstore              0.2                      py38_0
winpty                    0.4.3                         4
wrapt                     1.12.1           py38he774522_1
xlrd                      2.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
xlsxwriter                1.4.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
xlwings                   0.24.3           py38haa95532_0
xlwt                      1.3.0                    py38_0
xz                        5.2.5                h62dcd97_0
yaml                      0.2.5                he774522_0
yapf                      0.31.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
yarl                      1.6.3            py38h2bbff1b_0
zeromq                    4.3.3                ha925a31_3
zfp                       0.5.5                hd77b12b_6
zict                      2.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
zipp                      3.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
zlib                      1.2.11           vc14h1cdd9ab_1  [vc14]  anaconda
zope                      1.0                      py38_1
zope.event                4.5.0                    py38_0
zope.interface            5.4.0            py38h2bbff1b_0
zstd                      1.4.9                h19a0ad4_0s
```

Comment: Does [this post](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/1477#issuecomment-767677551) answer your question?

Comment: @user696969 I tried this method, but it was useless, thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Hi! Can your `test the same code in new environment after installing through "pip install tensorflow" command`. As this command is able to configure environment for both GPU and CPU simultaneously ,